# org.jboss.resteasy.spi.interception.PreProcessInterceptor vs Spring MVC Interceptor

Tags: spring-boot

Looking for Equivalent interceptor to PreProcessInterceptor.java (org.jboss.resteasy.spi.interception.PreProcessInterceptor ) (https://howtodoinjava.com/resteasy/jax-rs-resteasy-basic-authentication-and-authorization-tutorial/)

Trying to find a interceptor with code snippet to get the user and check whether he has permission to access the requested URL

1. Equivalent interceptor to PreProcessInterceptor.java in Spring MVC
2. Interceptor code to authorize user action

Comment: Any comments on this?

Comment: Anybody have any suggestions ???